# get HTML element from template in Angular 7

Tags: angular

is there a way I can get my "# content" variable in my app.module.ts file?

My file of example in HTML

```
   <div #content>
      .....
   </div>
```

My file of example app.module.ts

```
    //How do I get my variable here?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template

Comment: Why do you need the variable in your App.module?

Comment: @Roy not quite the same, but I understood how to do it now. They already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it with:

```
@ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;
```

A more indepth look is here:
https://medium.com/@toannm4/angular-nativeelement-how-to-read-nativeelement-using-viewchild-cdf4a0970482